# Type-safe equals macro?

Tags: scala, macros, equals

Is there a type-safe equals `===` implementation for Scala that has zero overhead over `==`? That is, unlike `===` in Scalaz and ScalaUtils, an implementation that uses a straight macro to perform the check?

I would like to use `===` in many places but these are hot-spots, so I don't want that to incur any extra runtime costs (like constructing type classes and such).

Comment: What would a macro implementation buy you over an implicit value class?

Comment: @TravisBrown value classes save the allocation cost, but don't save the indirection cost, if I'm not mistaken. This might be relevant: http://typelevel.org/blog/2015/08/06/machinist.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve it easily with [machinist](https://github.com/typelevel/machinist).

The README on GitHub gives exactly the `===` example:

```
import scala.{specialized => sp}

import machinist.DefaultOps

trait Eq[@sp A] {
  def eqv(lhs: A, rhs: A): Boolean
}

object Eq {
  implicit val intEq = new Eq[Int] {
    def eqv(lhs: Int, rhs: Int): Boolean = lhs == rhs
  }

  implicit class EqOps[A](x: A)(implicit ev: Eq[A]) {
    def ===(rhs: A): Boolean = macro DefaultOps.binop[A, Boolean]
  }
}
```

then you can use `===` with zero overhead (no extra allocations, no extra indirection) over `==`

---

If you are looking for a out-of-the-box implementation, [`spire`](https://github.com/non/spire) (from which machinist originated) provides one.

Also [`cats`](https://github.com/non/cats) provides one.

They're both macro-based as they use `machinist` for the implementation.

Comment: The implementations in spire and cats both require type class instances, though, so you'd have to take care that you're not instantiating those on each use, etc.

Comment: @TravisBrown, not sure I follow. As long as you don't use `ev` from `EqOps` you should be fine, as the type class is only used as proof of availability of an equality operation. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer based on Machinist is probably best. Here is a more hackish variant that detects cases such as inferring `Any` or `AnyRef` or the typical mix of two unrelated case classes (`Product with Serializable`):

```
import scala.collection.breakOut
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object Implicits {
  implicit class TripleEquals[A](a: A) {
    def === [B >: A](b: B): Boolean = macro Macros.equalsImpl[A, B]
  }
}

object Macros {
  private val positiveList = Set("scala.Boolean", "scala.Int", "scala.Long",
                                 "scala.Float", "scala.Double", "scala.Option)
  private val negativeList = Set("java.lang.Object", "java.io.Serializable",
                                 "<refinement>")

  def equalsImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag, B: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)
                                                    (b: c.Expr[A]): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    val bTpe = weakTypeOf[B]
    val base = bTpe.baseClasses
    val names: Set[String] = base.collect {
      case sym if sym.isClass => sym.fullName
    } (breakOut)

    // if a primitive is inferred, we're good. otherwise:
    if (names.intersect(positiveList).isEmpty) {
      // exclude all such as scala.Product, scala.Equals
      val withoutTopLevel = names.filterNot { n =>
        val i = n.lastIndexOf('.')
        i == 5 && n.startsWith("scala")
      }
      // exclude refinements and known Java types
      val excl = withoutTopLevel.diff(negativeList)
      if (excl.isEmpty) {
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Inferred type is too generic: `$bTpe`")
      }
    }

    // now simply rewrite as `a == b`
    val q"$_($a)" = c.prefix.tree
    q"$a == $b"
  }
}
```

This doesn't work with higher-kinded types, yet, so tuples are deliberately failing, while unfortunately `Some(1) === Some("hello")` compiles.

---

**Edit**: A built [a small library](https://github.com/Sciss/Equal) that improves on this to support higher-kinded types.